# SapUI5- Backspace not working on Input tag

Tags: sapui5

I have an Input tag of type "Text" where I want the user to enter only in uppercase , hence I am using liveChange event for this. Its working fine in browser but for some reason, when I run it on phone the backspace on the keypad is not working. Not able to understand why.

```html
<Input liveChange="handleChange" id="userName" type="Text" />
```

```js
//Function  
handleChange : function(){
  var userName=this.getView().byId("userName").getValue();
  userName=userName.toUpperCase();
  this.getView().byId("userName").setValue(userName);
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: See the example here http://jsbin.com/wiqofodoriki/1/edit, it works for me.

Comment: @Allen.Can u tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually my code is working in browser but not on phone

Comment: Please specify it in your question.